# What is "self-contained university teaching"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From the [Habilitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation) page in Wikipedia:

> Habilitation is a qualification required in order to conduct **self-contained university teaching**, and to obtain a professorship in many European countries

I googled for "self-contained teaching" and found definitions related to schools only:

> The term “self-contained classroom” refers to a classroom, where a special education teacher is responsible for the instruction of all academic subjects. The classroom is typically separated from general education classrooms but within a neighborhood school.

What is the meaning of "self-contained" in relation to universities? Does it mean that a person holding habilitation is able to teach a full course of a particular subject, instead of just giving a single lecture? Or that he is able to teach a course with no other lectors participating to help him out?

Comment: Since this is a specific, technical term of art (in pedagogy theory), I don't think this is the best place to find a full answer to your question.  There's certainly not enough information in the definition you quote to answer your questions below!  And it's not a phrase that most English speakers know.

Comment: The term in Wikipedia may be wrong in the context. Maybe it should be "self-directed", that is not as a teaching assistant, but as a full professor. The rest of the linked  article seems to support that.